# Unified connection string for MS SQL Express and SQL LocalDb?

Tags: web-config, connection-string, sql-server-express, localdb

I need to support SQL Express and LocalDb in my ASP.NET application. This is a sample app for demo purposes and not a real website.

Currently the app is shipped with LocalDb connection string:

```
<add name="Conn" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDB.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If user has SQL Express installed only, he must update the connection string to be:

```
<add name="Conn"
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDB.mdf;User Instance=true"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is it possible to specify connection string so that both SQL Express and SQL LocalDb are supported and user do not need to update the connection string?

I can update my sample application to test Sql Express and Local DB presence and choose the required string automatically, but want to avoid this, because I need to keep the app as simple as possible with minimum code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a "universal" connection string is possible. It would defeat the purpose of the connection string, which is to provide information for a particular data store running on a particular technology.

If your problem is that you develop on LocalDB and have production in say SQL Server Express, you can take advantage of [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) to select the connection string based on the environment to which you are deploying.